# How to get javascript function value into variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have Index.cshtml page with code

```
<h2>Calculation and approval of bonuses</h2>
<script>
    function getview() {
        var d = 2
        return d;
    }
</script>
@{ 
   int i=getview()?????????

    ;}
```

how to I can get into variable "i" the result from getview() function.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot use js function in C# code.You an try to call a c# method in c# code.

Comment: Thanks, negative answer is result too:)